# How to find which pod is taking more data ingestion in AKS cluster using kql query?

Tags: azure-aks, kql, azure-log-analytics, data-ingestion

I am trying to figure out which pod is producing more billable data ingestion in AKS for log analytics.

I tried several queries and I found only a query that checks the particular node

Is there any query to check the whole pod data ingestion per namespace to find out billable data ingestion?

Thank you?

Answer (score 0):

The default query shows logs per container, and not per pod as you would expected from a Kubernetes-specific logging system.

***You can use below KQL query in Log Analytics Workspace -> View Designer -> click on logs button in the header->Logging AKS Test->Container Log.***

```
let startTimestamp = ago(1h);
KubePodInventory
| where TimeGenerated > startTimestamp
| project ContainerID, PodName=Name
| distinct ContainerID, PodName
| join
(
    ContainerLog
    | where TimeGenerated > startTimestamp
)
on ContainerID
// at this point before the next pipe, columns from both tables are available to be "projected". Due to both 
// tables having a "Name" column, we assign an alias as PodName to one column which we actually want
| project TimeGenerated, PodName, LogEntry, LogEntrySource
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

For more information please refer this [***Document***](https://blog.coffeeapplied.com/using-azure-monitor-logs-with-azure-kubernetes-service-aks-c0b0625295d1)